# How to add existing child to a new parent

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using entity framework.

My model is like this :

**Group** : ID , Name

**User** : Id, Name , GroupID.

The situation is this :
I have a User (User1) that is not member of any group.

I create a new group and want to add this user to this new group.

I have this code :

```
Dim grp1 as new Group
grp1.name="Students"
context.Groups.Add(grp1)
context.savechanges()
usr1.GroupID=grp1.ID
context.savechanges()
```

This code works , but I have called twice the SaveChanges.
Is there any way to attach the existing usr1 to child collection of grp1 and after to call Savechanges only one time ?

Thank you !

Comment: Have you tried removing the first context.SaveChanges()? I think the two Add()'s will still work right.

Comment: If you want to add the `User` to the `Users` collection of that `Group` then that is what you would do: `grp1.Users.Add(usr1)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney but usr1 exist , and is not a new object.

Comment: @andriano is the usr1 is a tracker object ? Is it fetched from the context ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `usr1` is a tracked entity then you can add the group onto the user's `Group` navigational property instead of trying to use the Id.

```
Dim grp1 as new Group
grp1.name="Students"
usr1.Group=grp1
context.savechanges()
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

> By assigning a new object to a navigation property. The following code
>   creates a relationship between a course and a department. If the
>   objects are attached to the context, the course is also added to the
>   department.Courses collection, and the corresponding foreign key
>   property on the course object is set to the key property value of the
>   department. course.Department = department;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx (see blog examples)

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    // Add a new User by setting a reference from a tracked Blog 
    var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1); 
    blog.Owner = new User { UserName = "johndoe1987" }; 

    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```